# Integrating Intuit Quick Books with Website

Tags: quickbooks

I want to be able to connect my website with Quick Books, but I really can't find much if any information on how to do so. Basically all I want to be able to do is when an order is placed and an invoice number is captured, it then enters that invoice number and payment amount into Quickbooks.  Have any of you done this, or have any information you could provide?

Update:

This is going to be done in PHP and the Quickbooks is the Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

Research Quickbooks ODBC driver.

Here's a link from my initial search engine query: http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/support/Articles/INF12836

Warning: You are likely to experience great pain and displeasure if you go down this route.

Comment: Displeasure with trying to connect Quickbooks to a website, or displeasure with the ODBC driver?  So far it's been displeasure overall.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit now that you told us what programming language and QuickBooks version you're using:**

Go grab this open source PHP library for QuickBooks:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Follow the quick-start guide linked there:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start

Read a bit more about the QuickBooks Web Connector, which is what you'll be using to exchange data using PHP:

- http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Web_Connector_Overview

Basically, you're going to end up with some code like this:

```
function _quickbooks_customer_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
    // You'd probably do some database access here to pull the record with 
    //  ID = $ID from your database and build a request to add that particular 
    //  customer to QuickBooks. 
    //  
    // So, when you implement this for your business, you'd probably do 
    //  something like this...: 

    /*
    // Fetch your customer record from your database
    $record = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM your_customer_table WHERE your_customer_ID_field = " . (int) $ID));

    // Create and return a qbXML request
    $qbxml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <CustomerAdd>
                        <Name>' . $record['your_customer_name_field'] . '</Name>
                        <CompanyName>' . $record['your_customer_company_field'] . '</CompanyName>

                        ... lots of other customer related fields ...

                    </CustomerAdd>
                </CustomerAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';

    return $qbxml;
    */

    // But we're just testing, so we'll just use a static test request:

    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <CustomerAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <CustomerAdd>
                        <Name>ConsoliBYTE, LLC (' . mt_rand() . ')</Name>
                        <CompanyName>ConsoliBYTE, LLC</CompanyName>
                        <FirstName>Keith</FirstName>
                        <LastName>Palmer</LastName>
                        <BillAddress>
                            <Addr1>ConsoliBYTE, LLC</Addr1>
                            <Addr2>134 Stonemill Road</Addr2>
                            <City>Mansfield</City>
                            <State>CT</State>
                            <PostalCode>06268</PostalCode>
                            <Country>United States</Country>
                        </BillAddress>
                        <Phone>860-634-1602</Phone>
                        <AltPhone>860-429-0021</AltPhone>
                        <Fax>860-429-5183</Fax>
                        <Email>Keith@ConsoliBYTE.com</Email>
                        <Contact>Keith Palmer</Contact>
                    </CustomerAdd>
                </CustomerAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';

    return $xml;
}

function _quickbooks_invoice_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <InvoiceAddRq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <InvoiceAdd>
                        <CustomerRef>
                            <FullName>Keith Palmer Jr.</FullName>
                        </CustomerRef>
                        <TxnDate>2009-01-09</TxnDate>
                        <RefNumber>16466</RefNumber>
                        <BillAddress>
                            <Addr1>Keith Palmer Jr.</Addr1>
                            <Addr3>134 Stonemill Road</Addr3>
                            <City>Storrs-Mansfield</City>
                            <State>CT</State>
                            <PostalCode>06268</PostalCode>
                            <Country>United States</Country>
                        </BillAddres>
                        <InvoiceLineAdd>
                            <ItemRef>
                                <FullName>Gift Certificate</FullName>
                            </ItemRef>
                            <Desc>$25.00 gift certificate</Desc>
                            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                            <Rate>25.00</Rate>
                            <SalesTaxCodeRef>
                                <FullName>NON</FullName>
                            </SalesTaxCodeRef>
                        </InvoiceLineAdd>
                        <InvoiceLineAdd>
                            <ItemRef>
                                <FullName>Book</FullName>
                            </ItemRef>
                            <Desc>The Hitchhiker\'s Guide to the Galaxy</Desc>
                            <Amount>19.95</Amount>
                            <SalesTaxCodeRef>
                                <FullName>TAX</FullName>
                            </SalesTaxCodeRef>
                        </InvoiceLineAdd>
                    </InvoiceAdd>
                </InvoiceAddRq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';

    return $xml;
}
```

**Original answer:**

<strike>You didn't tell us what programming language you're using, or what version of QuickBooks you're using (Online vs. for Windows are two totally separate products with completely different APIs) so you're not going to get much in the way of details without updating your question, but... 
If you're using QuickBooks *for Windows*:</strike>

- use the Web Connector, in conjunctions with the QuickBooks SDK
- description of how the Web Connector works here: http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector

If you're using QuickBooks *Online*:

- Use the v3 APIs
- tons of docs on this here: https://developer.intuit.com/

There are about a bazillion Stack Overflow questions that already address specifics of integration with each of these products as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've done several integrations using a direct COM connection from PHP to QBD (either called manually or with a scheduled task depending on the requirements).

<s>See my answer to a question on Intuit's forum:
https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/916537-php-connect-to-quickbooks-desktop-using-qbxmlrp-com-object</s> [Quickbooks developer site updated so this link is DOA ... I've included the post info directly below. This code is almost 10 years old and copy-pasted, so may need a little love ... but it is what I continue to use to this day in 2022.]

With php_com_dotnet.dll enabled, it is quite easy & reliable to integrate directly to QBD. After connecting, I use QBXML requests to push and pull info to & from Quickbooks.

But first just to clarify: Since Intuit is no longer supporting use of the QBD versions of the API, any kind of dynamic integration to QBD is limited to applications built to leverage what Intuit calls the Quickbooks Desktop SDK. The Web Connector is one such application (supplied & maintained directly by Intuit) which is designed to offer a web-service-style middle man between Quickbooks and a web application, such as an e-commerce site. There are a number of third-party PHP libraries designed to communicate with various web sites written in PHP and the Web Connector. There is also the PHP DevKit, which offers a number of foundational classes for custom development of PHP / Web-Connector based integrations.

But PHP for windows continues to support a COM class extension (php_com_dotnet.dll) out of the box, with only the enabling of the extension in php.ini required. That means that, using only PHP scripts, you can write an application built to leverage the Quickbooks Desktop SDK directly. And you do not need to install the actual SDK, which is actually just tools for building a more traditional windows application.

There are plenty of considerations & gotchas involved with this type of integration with QBD (and shouldn't you be using QuickBooks Online instead?), so there may be cases where this is not a good idea. But if you want to go for it, rest assured that it works fine and can certainly be used in a production environment if your PHP code is well-written.

Here is a very basic version of the code I am using:

First, to connect:

```
<?php

...

$empty_variant = new VARIANT();
$quickbooks = null;
$qb_session = null;
$app_name = 'My Test PHP App';
$qbxml_version = '13.0'; // note: this is _not_ the version of QBD in use!

try {
    $quickbooks = new COM('QBXMLRP2.RequestProcessor');
    $quickbooks->OpenConnection2($empty_variant, $app_name, 1);
    $qb_session = $quickbooks->BeginSession($empty_variant, 2);
} catch (com_exception $e) {
    die ('ERROR: QB COM Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

...
?>
```

(The 1 parameter in OpenConnection2 indicates to connect to local QBD instance [it should be open and it will prompt for permissions the first time you run your script] and the 2 parameter in BeginSession indicates to connect in either single- or multi-user mode [i.e., the app doesn't care].)

Once you have a connection & session, you can use the ProcessRequest function to send and receive QBXML. E.g., here is retrieving an account list:

```
<?php
...

$xml = xmlwriter_open_memory ();
xmlwriter_start_document ($xml, '1.0', 'utf-8');
    xmlwriter_start_element ($xml, 'QBXML');
        xmlwriter_start_element ($xml, 'QBXMLMsgsRq');
            xmlwriter_write_attribute ($xml, 'onError', 'stopOnError');
            xmlwriter_start_element ($xml, 'AccountQueryRq');
                xmlwriter_write_attribute ($xml, 'metaData', 'MetaDataAndResponseData');
            xmlwriter_end_element ($xml);
        xmlwriter_end_element ($xml);
    xmlwriter_end_element ($xml);
xmlwriter_end_document ($xml);
$xml = xmlwriter_output_memory ($xml);
$xml = str_replace ('<QBXML>', . "<" . "?qbxml version=\"{$qbxml_version}}\"?" . ">\n<QBXML>", $xml);


try {
    $response = $quickbooks->ProcessRequest($qb_session, $xml);
} catch (com_exception $e) {
    die ('ERROR: QB COM Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

// parse response
if (!$response_xml = simplexml_load_string ($response)) {
    die ('ERROR: Unable to parse QB response XML: ' . $response);
}

$response = $response_xml->QBXMLMsgsRs->AccountQueryRs;

// check errors ...
if ((string) $response['statusCode'] != '0') {
    die ('ERROR: QB returned status ' . (string) $response['statusCode'] . ' (' . (string) $response['statusMessage'] . ')');
}

// collect active accounts only
$accounts = array ();
if ((int) $response['retCount'] > 0) {
    foreach ($response->AccountRet as $e) {
        if ((string) $e->IsActive != 'true') continue;
        $accounts[] = array ('name' => (string) $e->Name, 'id' => (string) $e->ListID,);
    }
}

print_r($accounts);

...
?>
```

Note that you will be running your PHP in a command window in the same console session as QBD. Or, if you have a local PHP web app, you will need to be running Apache in console (not as a service).

I've also used the API & Web Connector. The API is no longer supported for Desktop Quickbooks. The Web Connector / DevKit combo works, too, and seems to be the most popular approach with the best "community" support. When not using the WebConnector, I really appreciate the simplicity, though.